# How to avoid pyramid of doom in three database operations?

Tags: ios, swift, refactoring, swift3

There are three database operations I need to perform once I receive data from web services

```
   self.save(responses, child: child, year: year, completionBlock:
     {(success, error) in
           self.saveModifiedDate(child, year: year, completionBlock: { (result) in
            self.fetchAll(child, year: year!, completionBlock: completionBlock)
            })
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using or implementing yourself (It's not that hard) a Future-like API. A good framework is [FutureKit](https://github.com/FutureKit/FutureKit).

The code would then look like

```
save(responses, child: child, year: year)
  .onSuccess(saveModifiedDate)
  .onSuccess(fetchAll)
  .onSuccess { //final completion handler }
  .onFailure { //handle error }
```